# unordered_map in class, member function already defined or declared?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm getting several "member function already defined or declared" errors. What is or could be causing this? I'm still fairly new to C++ and STL and don't believe I redefined this (I have not used an unordered_map anywhere else besides the files below).

[image]

LuaLibrary.h:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unknwn.h>
#include "wrapper/IUnknownImpl.h"
#include "Lua/src/lua.hpp"
#include "aimp/Sources/Cpp/apiGUI.h"

// Library
class IAIMPLua : public IUnknown {
    virtual HRESULT GetService(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject) = 0;
    virtual void CollectGarbage() = 0;
};

class AIMPLua : public IUnknownImpl<IAIMPLua> {
private:
    std::unordered_map<REFIID, void*>* services;
public:
    AIMPLua();
    ~AIMPLua();
    static AIMPLua* LoadLib(lua_State* L);
    virtual HRESULT GetService(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);
    virtual void CollectGarbage();
};
```

LuaLibrary.cpp:

```cpp
#include "LuaLibrary.h"

AIMPLua::AIMPLua() {
    services = new std::unordered_map<REFIID, void*>();
}

AIMPLua::~AIMPLua() {
    delete services;
}

AIMPLua* AIMPLua::LoadLib(lua_State* L) {
    AIMPLua* lib = new AIMPLua();
    // Test
    IAIMPServiceUI* uiService;
    HRESULT r = lib->GetService(IID_IAIMPServiceUI, (void**)&uiService);
    lib->CollectGarbage();
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `std::unordered_map<REFIID, void*>* services;`?

Comment: I'm using it as a form of cache to avoid calling QueryInterface multiple times within the same set of tasks.

Comment: I don't mean for what, I mean why is `services` a pointer?

Comment: I didn't see a reason to store it directly since `new` returns a pointer to it. If there is a benefit to storing it more directly, would love to know.

Comment: I'm not sure why the problem manifests this way, but you can't use a reference as a key in the map. `REFIID` is a typedef for `const IID&`. `std::unordered_map<IID, void*>` might work.

Comment: Those errors I mentioned have gone away, so I think that was the solution. Now it is telling me, "attempting to reference a deleted function" for _Uhash_compare. I'm assuming that is unrelated. Post that comment as an answer and I'll be happy to mark it as such.

Comment: Can confirm, that followup error was unrelated.